# Android - How to make an app displayed in a small screen while the rest of screen is still visible and clickable

Tags: android

I have a request to reduce my app screen size and the rest of the screen space are still visible and clickable for user.
It means when my app is running, user can click some icons or buttons outside of my application.

What I found are using such as Dialogs or Multiple Fragments. However, those solutions are useful when all are in your main activity. But in my case, the rest of the screen is from Home screen or other screens, not from my app screen.
Could someone have an idea for this kind of concept?

Here is my request concept image
[image]

Searching from internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything for this. Android supports [splitt screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/multi-window-support) since Android 7.0.

Alternatively you can [enable Picture-In-Picture](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/picture-in-picture) mode for your app which is supported since Android 8.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion.
Using Picture-in-Picture mode seems to be a good approach at the moment.